# HTML table partial border on a column

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a border on the right of the column called "Name". The border I want it to go from 50% of the top of the row "Name" and that it goes all the way to the bottom to the "Cost" row, however, in the cost row I also want it to be 50% height so it doesn't reach the very bottom of the table. Can someone help me how can I achieve this?

```css
icon {
  position: absolute;
  left:-10rem;
  top:-19rem;
}

table {
    border-top: 5px solid black;
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 10rem;
    width:70%;
    border-collapse: collapse !important;
    border-spacing: 0 !important;
  }
  th {
    text-align:center!important;
    background-color: green;
    padding: 1rem !important
  }
  td {
    text-align:center;
    line-height:.8em !important;
    background-color: gray
  }
  .services {
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:left;
//  border-right: 1px solid black !important;
  }
  .pricing{
    font-weight:bold;
  }
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/cats/" style="width:50px;height:50px" class="icon"/>
<table class="table borderless">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Plan A</th>
      <th>Plan B</th>
      <th>Plan C</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="services">Description 1</td>
      <td class="included"></td>
      <td class="included"></td>
      <td class="included"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="services">Description 2</td>
      <td>Not Included</td>
      <td class="included"></td>
      <td class="included"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="services">Description 3</td>
      <td>Not Included</td>
      <td class="included"></td>
      <td class="included"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="services">Description 4</td>
      <td>Not Included</td>
      <td>Not Included</td>
      <td class="included"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="services">Description 5</td>
      <td>Not Included</td>
      <td>Not Included</td>
      <td class="included"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="services">Description 6</td>
      <td>Not Included</td>
      <td>Not Included</td>
      <td class="included"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="services">Description 7</td>
      <td>Limited</td>
      <td>Hight Quality</td>
      <td>Customized</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="services">Description 8</td>
      <td>Limited</td>
      <td>Hight Quality</td>
      <td>Customized</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="services">Description 9</td>
      <td>Limited</td>
      <td>Hight Quality</td>
      <td>Customized</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="pricing">
      <td style="padding-bottom: 2rem !important;" class="table-services">Cost</td>
      <td>Price A</td>
      <td>Price B</td>
      <td>Price C</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you want it to look like in the end?

Comment: What is code in your .css file? Is it include in html file?

Comment: Just edited with css and a screenshot of what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Draw the borders with pseudo elements.

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 0 solid;
  border-width: 2px 0;
}
th, td {
  position: relative;
}
th:first-child:before,
td:first-child:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  background: black;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
th:first-child:before {
  top: auto;
  height: 50%;
}
tr:last-child td:first-child:before {
  bottom: auto;
  height: 50%;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lfn5Lvqw/)**

Or use background gradient.

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 0 solid;
  border-width: 2px 0;
}
th:first-child,
td:first-child {
  background: linear-gradient(black 50%, black 50%) top right / 1px 100% no-repeat;
}
th:first-child {
  background-position: bottom right;
  background-size: 1px 50%;
}
tr:last-child td:first-child {
  background-size: 1px 50%;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z888pjm7/)**

Comment: This seems to work, though I have a small icon on the top left corner of the table that when I add this, the portion of the icon inside of the first header row doesn't show as it seems it goes to the back. The icon is using .icon {
  position: absolute;
  left:-8rem;
  top:-14rem;
}

Comment: @J.Rem That is probably due the relative position being add to the table cells, are you able to move that icon out of the table or not to use absolute position? I also added another solution with background gradient and no position properties.

Comment: I just realized that with this solution, in Firefox, the border looks a bit cut off at the bottom on the first row/first header. Why is that? how can I fix it?

Comment: @J.Rem It looks fine here, it's probably caused by your other styles I think.

Answer (score 0):

Using a pseudoelement...

```css
td:nth-child(1) {
  width: 275px;
}

table {
  position: relative;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

table:after {
  content: "";
  height: 215px;
  width: 1px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table class="table borderless">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Plan A</th>
      <th>Plan B</th>
      <th>Plan C</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="services">Description 1</td>
      <td class="included"></td>
      <td class="included"></td>
      <td class="included"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="services">Description 2</td>
      <td>Not Included</td>
      <td class="included"></td>
      <td class="included"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="services">Description 3</td>
      <td>Not Included</td>
      <td class="included"></td>
      <td class="included"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="services">Description 4</td>
      <td>Not Included</td>
      <td>Not Included</td>
      <td class="included"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="services">Description 5</td>
      <td>Not Included</td>
      <td>Not Included</td>
      <td class="included"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="services">Description 6</td>
      <td>Not Included</td>
      <td>Not Included</td>
      <td class="included"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="services">Description 7</td>
      <td>Limited</td>
      <td>Hight Quality</td>
      <td>Customized</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="services">Description 8</td>
      <td>Limited</td>
      <td>Hight Quality</td>
      <td>Customized</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="services">Description 9</td>
      <td>Limited</td>
      <td>Hight Quality</td>
      <td>Customized</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="pricing">
      <td style="padding-bottom: 2rem !important;" class="table-services">Cost</td>
      <td>Price A</td>
      <td>Price B</td>
      <td>Price C</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a reference

[image]

```
<table cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="col-header"> <span class="">Name</span>
        </td>
        <td class="col-header"> <span class="">Plan A</span>
        </td>
        <td class="col-header"> <span class="">Plan B</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col-header highlight">
        </td>
        <td >
        </td>
        <td class="">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="text">description 1
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">v 1-1
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">v 1-2
        </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="text">description 2
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">v 2-1
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">v 2-2
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col-header text"><span class="mobile-photo">Cost</span>
        </td>
        <td class="col-header"> <span class="mobile-photo">Price A</span>
        </td>
        <td class="col-header"> <span class="mobile-photo">Price B</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

css

```
.col-header{
 width: 100px;
 height: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 color: black;
 vertical-align:middle;
 position: relative;
}
.col-header > span {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 top: 15px;
 z-index:2;
 vertical-align: middle;
 line-height: 20px;
}   

.col-header.highlight{ 
 border-right-color: #ff0000;
 border-right-style: solid;
}

.text-center{
 text-align:center
}
.text{
 width:100px;
 border-right-color: #ff0000;
 border-right-style: solid;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using the `:first-child()` pseudo-element:

```
table.borderless { 
    tbody {
        tr {
            td {
                &:first-child {
                    border-right: 2px solid black;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dude you just copied what I have hahaha

Comment: Yes, that is what he wants, but the table cell have padding which needs to be taken away.